# Export Using Kivy to Android(Python)

Tags: python, kivy

I've made a few Kivy projects and I'm completely lost on how to export them to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using Linux**, then the easiest way would probably be to use Buildozer. You can install it with

```
sudo pip install buildozer
```

After that, you can go into your project's directory and then run

```
buildozer init
```

It will create `buildozer.spec` file, where you can change some options like app name, version, orientation, icon etc. After you modify it, then you can run

```
buildozer android debug
```

which will create "bin" directory (in your project's directory), where you can find your .apk file.

**If you are not using Linux**, then you can directly use python-for-android (which is automatically used with Buildozer too) as described [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-with-python-for-android). Honestly, if your are going to export your apps to Android often, then it might be better to get Linux at least on a virtual machine, since this is so much easier to do with Buildozer.